# Different behavior between loop of a variable and an argument in batch file, argument can't be passed in a loop

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I'm trying to extract the batch file argument into 3 strings. I tried first using a variable then splitting it into 3 (delimiter is a space):

Code:

```
@echo off
set var=\s v4.12 1,2,3,4
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in ("%var%") do (
echo a is %%a, b is %%b, c is %%c
)
```

Result:

```
a is \s, b is v4.12, c is 1,2,3,4
```

But when I tried implementing the var into argument:

New code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%a in ("%1") do (
echo a is %%a, b is %%b, c is %%c
)
```

Execution:

```
test.bat \s v4.12 1,2,3,4
```

Result:

```
a is /s, b is , c is
```

I tried turning on the echo and found out that the argument wasn't passed in the loop, how do I fix it?

==========
EDIT (this is in response to Aacini's answer):

My current code:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%*") do (
echo First is %%a, Second is %%b, Third is %%c
:loopers
for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%d in ("%%c") do (
echo %%d
shift
if not  "%%d"=="" (
goto :loopers else exit >nul
)
)
)
```

After getting the 3rd token (%%c is equal to 1,2,3,4) I have to create a loop again to get each number by using comma as a delimiter but when I tried, it infinitely displays %c (not the value but the actual %c text)

This is the result:

```
First is /s, Second is v1.4, Third is 1,2,3,4
1
%c
..infinite loop of %c..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, I think I don't understand your question.

You want to execute this line:

```
test.bat /s v1.1 1,3,4,5
```

and separate parameter in 3 tokens: "/s", "v1.1", "1,3,4,5"  **OR**  separate parameter in 6 tokens: "/s", "v1.1" "1", "3", "4", "5" **?**

If you want the first case, then this code do that:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%*") do (
echo First is %%a, Second is %%b, Third is %%c
)
```

If you want second case, then each parameter is already available in %1 to %6 replaceable parameters:

```
echo First is %1, Second is %2, Third is %3, Fourth is %4, Fifth is %5, Sixth is %6
```

If neither of these solutions are good for you, please explain whay you want in a *very* concise way! (don't mix up or put other cases as examples, just put "I want this...")

**EDIT:** *New answer as reply to new info*

Please, you must realize that I can *not* understand what you want reviewing examples. Because you have not said what you want I can only guess, so here we go again...

1- If you want to separate parameters in 3 tokens: "/s", "v1.1" and "1,3,4,5", I already show how to do that via %%a, %%b and %%c replaceable parameters.

2- If you want to separate parameters in 6 tokens: "/s", "v1.1" "1", "3", "4" and "5" and have access to all of them *at same time*, you may use %1..%6 Batch parameters.

3- If you want to separate parameters *in any number of tokens* (6 in this case) and process they *one by one*, use this code:

```
:nextParam
   if "%1" equ "" goto endParams
   echo %1
   shift
   goto nextParam
:endParams
```

4- If you want to *first* separate parameters in 3 tokens: "/s", "v1.1" and "1,3,4,5", and *then* further separate the third token (%%c) in four parts, then I can not fathom out what the purpose of this could be. However, for illustrative purposes only, this is the way to do that:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%*") do (
   echo First is %%a, Second is %%b, Third is %%c
   for %%d in (%%c) do echo %%d
)
```

5- If you want to *store* the 3 parameters in 3 variables, and eliminate commas in the third one, use this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%*") do (
   set First=%%a
   set Second=%%b
   set Third=%%c
)
set Third=%Third:,= %
```

I strongly suggest you to read the description of the Batch commands you use (via `HELP command`) and do *not* use anything you don't understand. Note that copy a code you don't understand, modify it and then ask "why my code does not work?" is a nonsense. It is better to ask specific questions about specific doubts you may have.

If no one of the 5 points above is what you want, then we can not further help you if you don't explain us what you want (with words, NOT via code examples)...

Antonio