# Splitting the parameter in a batch file multiple times

Tags: batch-file, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

Sample batch execution:

```
test.bat /s v1.1 1,3,4,5
```

I want to split the parameter into three tokens using space as a delimiter. The result should be:

1st token = /s

2nd token = /v1.1

3rd token = 1,3,4,5

Then the 3rd token will be split again using comma as a delimiter

The code below splits the arguments using common delimiters such as space, comma, etc.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PARAMS=

:_PARAMS_LOOP

SET PARAMS=%PARAMS%%1 
ECHO %1
SHIFT

IF NOT "%1"=="" GOTO _PARAMS_LOOP
```

Execution:

```
test.bat /s v4.1 1,2,3,4
```

Result:

```
/s
v4.1
1
3
4
5
```

I just want to use space as a delimiter, then in the 3rd token(1,3,4,5) I will split it again using comma as a delimiter and echo each of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different behavior between loop of a variable and an argument in batch file, argument can't be passed in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755646/different-behavior-between-loop-of-a-variable-and-an-argument-in-batch-file-arg)

Comment: Actually, I'm the one who asked that. This is a different scenario than the first one because I have to split it now multiple times

Comment: See my answer if your first question... Note that you have NOT accepted nor replied to _that_ question, but post an entirely similar new question half an hour later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that cmd recognizes a space, tab, comma, semicolon, or equals sign as command line delimiters unless they are wrapped in doublequotes.

> **Delimiters**
>
> Some characters in the command line are ignored by batch files,
>   depending on the DOS version, wether they are "escaped" or not, and
>   often depending on their location in the command line:
>
> - commas (",") are replaced by spaces, unless they are part of a string
>     in doublequotes
> - semicolons (";") are replaced by spaces, unless they
>     are part of a string in doublequotes
> - "=" characters are sometimes
>     replaced by spaces, not if they are part of a string in doublequotes
> - the first forward slash ("/") is replaced by a space only if it
>     immediately follows the command, without a leading space
> - multiple spaces are replaced by a single space, unless they are part of a
>     string in doublequotes
> - tabs are replaced by a single space
> - leading spaces before the first command line argument are ignored
>
> I know of several occasions where these seemingly useless "features" proved very
>   handy. Keep in mind, though, that these "features" may vary with the
>   operating systems used.
>
> More on command line parsing can be found on the PATH and FOR
>   (especially FOR's interactive examples) pages.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php